# DBeaver: increase font size in Database Navigator

Tags: dbeaver

I would like to increase font in `Database Navigator` tree. I found an option in `Appearance` `View and Editor folders` > `Tree and table views` nevertheless besides the font the distance between `tree items` is increasing as well.

Is it possible to keep items distance between each other to not increase and just increase the font somehow?

Answer (score 26):

To increase the UI font : Window > Preferences > User Interface > Appearance > Colors and Fonts > DBeaver Fonts > Main font.

To increase the Script font : Window > Preferences > User Interface > Appearance > Colors and Fonts > DBeaver Fonts > Monospace font.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to achieve something similar. So, along with changing the font sizes, configuring the scale factor as described in the [github issue here](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/1391#issuecomment-330358032) worked for me.